# How can I copy protection file to another directory on ubuntu (in terminal)

Tags: ubuntu, directory, copy, cp

I what to copy this file (spring-jdbc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar) in /usr/lib/ambari-server

to /usr/share/java ( I want to replace it )

Comment: this is the error : cp spring-jdbc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar /usr/share/java/
cp: cannot stat 'spring-jdbc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar': No such file or directory     (Eddy Albines sent the solve of the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this

```
cp /usr/lib/ambari-server/spring-jdbc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar /usr/share/java/spring-jdbc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar
```